# How to query UCCX stored procedures from informix database using razorsql?

Tags: stored-procedures, informix, cisco, razorsql

I am new to stored procedures, informix, and UCCX. I am working on a project to consolidate reporting into on BI tool, and it appears there are several UCCX stored procedures that could be great time savers for bringing the UCCX historical reporting into our BI tools. Can anyone offer tips on how to query stored procedures for informix via RazorSQL?

Comment: What are the problems with executing the UCCX stored procedures the way you execute any other stored procedures?  Or is the problem that you don't know how to execute stored procedures — and UCCX is just a specific example of a set of stored procedures that you don't know how to invoke?  I've no idea what UCCX is (but I've not asked Google yet).  I don't know RazorSQL either.  But there are several ways to execute procedures (`EXECUTE PROCEDURE any_old_procedure(1, 'arg2', '2016-03-23')` for example).  At issue will be how to get argument values to and results back from the stored procedure.

Comment: UCCX is Cisco Unified Communication Platform (ACD Call system) and RazorSQL is just a SQL query tool. Here is one of the stored procedures that is included in the Cisco UCCX databases.

Comment: I am using the following syntax to execute the stored procedure
execute procedure gettotalcalls('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000','2016-02-01 00:00:00.000','1','1')

and I get the following error.
ERROR: [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]The specified 
table (calls_handled) is not in the database. Error Code: -206 

Query = execute procedure gettotalcalls('2016-01-01 
00:00:00.000','2016-02-01 00:00:00.000','1','1')

Comment: Hi, Ricky.  I do some work on the UCCX db side and came up your post by accident.  Just wondering if you had any luck with it?  I pull information from UCCX the Informix client SDK in order to post information to wallboards.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with your syntax. For example, I can call a different stored procedure by executing the following in RazorSQL:

```
execute procedure sp_agent_state_detail('2016-05-31 05:00:00','2016-05-31 05:59:59','0',null,'David Bowie',null,null)
```

The error you get is self-explanatory -- there is no calls_handled table. I suspect that the gettotalcalls() stored procedure is meant to be used in conjunction with some other code, perhaps another stored procedure, that creates that table.